# CSS Animations Overflow Across DIV's

Tags: css

I have a CSS3 Animation - a bouncing ball, that I'd like to travel over three distinct area.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindg/ny5rejk2/)

```
<div class="ball">
    <div class="col-1"></div><!--
  --><div class="col-2"></div><!--
  --><div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
<div>Ball Boucning Over DIV's</div>
```

So currently the ball is bouncing but it's taking the DIV's with it. This is because the animation is set at the parent DIV.

**How can I get the ball bouncing across all three child DIV's while keeping them stationary?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the layout to have a `<div style="position: relative;">` wrapping: one `<div>` for the ball with `position: absolute` and three childs `<div>`.
I also use `calc(100% - 160px)` for the bounce effect take full width.

http://jsfiddle.net/ny5rejk2/7/

I don't know if that's what you're looking for but the ball is bouncing across all three child.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I'm looking for!